# AudioToolBox leak in iOS6?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, ios6

When I use AudioToolBox for playing music, memory leaks heavily.

```
AVAudioPlayer *newMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];
```

I use this code to play music. In iOS5 and iOS4, it works properly. But in iOS6, if data's size is 5M, all of the 5M leaked. And I can't see leak info in Instruments.

Is there anybody have the same problem? Any suggestion will be grateful.

All my audio code here(Using ARC):

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    AVAudioPlayer *_player;
}

- (void)play
{
    if (_player)
    {
        [_player stop];
        _player = nil;
    }

    NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.app/1.mp3"];
    NSData *musicData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:musicData error:nil];
    player.volume = 1;
    if (player)
    {
        _player = player;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
    [button setTitle:@"play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(play) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

@end
```

Comment: check release notes exactly there has made some changes! at ios6

Comment: Do you observe the memory leak in the iOS simulator or a device? Or both?

Comment: In simulator. In fact, I can't get objc symbols on device in 4.5's Instruments, only c symbols show

Comment: @matheszabi i didn't find it in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS_DevLib_Release_Notes/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011648 is there any reference to it? Thanks

Comment: @OpenThread for the ios6 here is the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html MediaPlayer and Audio section, if those classes  has nothing with your class, than I am wrong

Comment: @matheszabi too bad it didn't metion about AVAudioPlayer, thanks anyway

Comment: @OpenThread have you the AVAudioPlayer source code, do you know what he use? :)

Comment: @matheszabi Of course not, it's a black box. I edited my question and added my code :)

Comment: @OpenThread Several askers here on SO (and me) have had the same issue with the simulator only. Try to profile your app on a device, and if it doesn't leak there, then don't worry about it.

Comment: @JereKäpyaho my device running iOS6 leaks too T_T

Comment: @JereKäpyaho any reference to codes doen't leak in device running iOS6 is grateful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm playing audio from a file using `AVAudioPlayer`, and found that the iOS simulator consistently leaks memory, but the device doesn't. This was verified using Instruments. This is ARC code.

My player is declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *numberPlayer;
```

and synthesized like this:

```
@synthesize numberPlayer = _numberPlayer;
```

Since I need to play several different sounds, and `AVAudioPlayer` cannot be reset to play a different audio file after its creation, I'm creating a new player every time, like this:

```
NSString *audioFilePathName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Voices/%@/%03i.m4a", self.voiceName, self.theNumber];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:BUNDLE_FULL_PATH(audioFilePathName)];
self.numberPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
self.numberPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
[self.numberPlayer setCurrentTime:0.0];
[self.numberPlayer setDelegate:self];
[self.numberPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.numberPlayer play];
```

In my delegate I set the player to `nil` when it has finished playing:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    if (player == self.numberPlayer) {
        _numberPlayer = nil;
    }
}
```

In the simulator, both `AudioSessionDevice` and `UISoundNewDevice` leak memory. However, the biggest leaker is actually `NSURL`. None of these leaks occur on the device. This behavior has not changed in iOS 6, but I do have my project deployment set to 5.0, should that make any difference.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433487/avaudioplayer-leak-in-simulator and [memory leak in AudioToolbox library AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915580/memory-leak-in-audiotoolbox-library-avaudioplayer).

Comment: initWithContentsOfURL: saves megabytes of memory, and only initWithData: leaks megabytes. I'm going to replace initWithData with initWithContentOfURL in my project. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you, you are right, the simulator shows an AudioToolbox leak but when I run on a device the leak is not present.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you did better than me and I haven't the XCode in my front, but :

object created, reference created:

```
AVAudioPlayer *newMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];
```

it is assignment and not allocation, no retain:

```
_musicPlayer = newMusicPlayer;
```

out of function `playMusicWithMusicData` it would deallocate the `newMusicPlayer` and it would crash my code in other function when I use the `_musicPlayer`. The analyzer tool nagged so much as I made a retain, maybe a release too.

if you are using ios4, than isn't ARC this project.

in if branch:

```
    [_musicPlayer stop];
    _musicPlayer = nil;
```

I would check the `_musicPlayer` to not be nil, but that will not solve your problems.

No clue where it could be, if not in ios and probably there it will be:

Did solve if you change the delegate instead of self.

```
 _musicPlayer.delegate = self;
```

to any other class?

Comment: I created a test project and pasted its code in question, it has the same problem with my music project, leaks in iOS6 and normal in iOS4/5. I didn't even set any delegate to AVAudioPlayer, it doesn't make difference T___T