# how to play live streaming from url for a camera that broadcasting live

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to play a live stream video from server, like opentok or wowza media server. how to implement please share your knowledge..

> > An Ip camera record video and send it to server and server broadcast it and this is to receive and play in iphone

Comment: Try to play with video MPMOviePlayerviewcontroller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MPMovieplayerviewcontroller. It is perfect for streaming audio/video. I am also

use this for streaming audio in one of my App & also it looks like default player of iPhone.

Ok here is coding for use of this player as I am doing in my project:

```
    NSString *geturl = [[radiotablearray objectAtIndex:btntag]objectForKey:@"iurl"];
    NSLog(@"geturl..%@",geturl);
    NSURL *fileURL=[NSURL URLWithString:geturl];
    NSLog(@"fileURL..%@",fileURL);
    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
    moviePlayerController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerController];
[moviePlayerController.moviePlayer play];
```

Also add mediaplayer & Avfoundation framework in App.And add or import these two in .h file:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

& import `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`this in .m file. also make property of player like below in .h file:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerController;
 @property(strong,retain)  MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerController;
```

And add method where you want but also make changes in code according to your need I am just send you my implement code you just change it with your requirement. Best of luck.