# Memory leaks when playing a video iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I need to play a simple video on my app. I been looking on the internet on how to play a video and I found out that I need to import the MediaPlayer.framwork which I did. I have a Video named:

[image]

and the code that I have in order to play it:

```
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                 pathForResource:@"Final_Valores_Pacific" 
                 ofType:@"m4v"];


MPMoviePlayerController *player = 
                                [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
                                initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
```

I am missing the code to add it to a view but just that code creates a leak:

[image]

what is the right way of playing a video? how can avoid that memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting this leak on the simulator?  I got this on an app that I worked on in the past only on the simulator, but not on the iPhone.

There are similar questions about this too:

[iPhone: OpenAL & AudioToolbox leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837294/iphone-openal-audiotoolbox-leak)

Comment: My app crashes so I am trying to find out where are the leaks. It crashes when playing the videos sometimes. And when run that on the simulator it shows leaks so I am assuming those are the leaks. I will take a look at your link. Thanks..

Comment: @Tono Nam, that's what I suspected.  This issue has been around since around iOS 2, but Apple still has not fixed it.  Definitely a pain.

Answer (score 2):

When you `alloc` an object, you have to release it at the end:

```
// ...some code
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                 pathForResource:@"Final_Valores_Pacific" 
                 ofType:@"m4v"];


MPMoviePlayerController *player = 
                                [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
                                initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
// ...use player
[player release];
```

Comment: I need it. I release it when the video finish playing. sorry for not mentioning that...

Comment: If I release it right away I don't get the leaks which is good but I need the video to play. should I do autorelease instead?